# Prove the following trigonometric polynomial has $2n$ zeros

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

I am having a lot of trouble with this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated!

> Prove that the that the trigonometric polynomial $$a_0 + a_1\cos(x)+\cdots+a_n\cos(nx), $$ where the coefficients are all real and $|a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots+|a_{n-1}|\leq a_n$, has at least $2n$ zeros in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

I am pretty sure I have to use the Intermediate Value Theorem at some point but I am not really sure how to use it properly in this situation. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you know Fourier series ?

Comment: No, not at all, heard of the term but never ever had any exposure to it and I doubt I am expected to solve this through Fourier series (I hope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate your formula at $k\pi / n$ where $k = 0,1,2,\ldots,2n$, and focus on the leading term vs the sum of the other terms. You will get that the formula is negative for odd $k$ and positive for even $k$, based on the inequality on the coefficients and the fact that $|\cos x|$ is strictly less than 1 when $x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$. Then apply the intermediate value theorem like you said.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am still having difficulty understanding how to use the IVT here, I got that using the odd and even $k$ results in a negative and positive equation, respectively, but how does that get me at least $2n$ zeros?

Comment: @InsigMath You have $2n + 1$ points that alternate between positive and negative function values. In between each consecutive pair, therefore, you must get all function values in between the lesser value endpoint (which is negative) and the greater value endpoint (which is positive). So you must get function value 0 somewhere in between each consecutive pair of points, and there are $2n + 1$ points, so $2n$ zeros in the interval $(0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Ahh, I see now! That makes a lot of sense, so it really is applying the IVT 2n times since at every application I should be able to find a value $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$!

Comment: @InsigMath yes exactly. :) cheers