# How to show that two trigonometric polynomials of degree $n$ combined have at most $2n$ zeros?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials, roots

I am already aware of this question: [Prove the following trigonometric polynomial has $2n$ zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735387/prove-the-following-trigonometric-polynomial-has-2n-zeros)

But it's not the same.

Let be $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \cos (kx)$ and $\tilde{P}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cos((n - k)x)$.

If we denote $Z(Q)$ the number of zeros of $Q$ (we count without multiplicities, so: $Z(X^2) = 1$), then, how can we show that, that over $[0, 2\pi[$ :

\begin{equation*}
Z(P) + Z(\tilde{P}) \leq 2n
\end{equation*}

I know that I can show that: $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cos(kx)$ have at most $2n$ zeros, using an imaginary exponential form and the fact that $x \mapsto e^{ix}$ is a bijection from $[0, 2\pi[$ to $\mathbb{U}$ the set of complex of module $1$.

But I don't know how to relate those two polynomials to an exponential imaginary form, I tried to expand $\cos((n - k)x)$ to create $\sin, \cos$ expressions, but without luck.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My bad, I meant without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. If we take $P(x)=1-\cos(x)+\cos(2x)$ we have $n=2$ and $\tilde{P}(x)=P(x)$.
$Z(P)=4$ then leads to $Z(P)+Z(\tilde{P})=8\gg 4$.

Comment: What if we ask about distinct roots of $Z(P), Z(\tilde P)$? I think that if $a_k$ are real there is a good chance the result may be true in the sense that the number of distinct roots of $P\tilde P=0$ is still at most $2n$, but of course I could be wrong...

Comment: @Conrad: that was my suspect, in a deleted comment I wondered about the original exercise being about the distinct roots of $P\tilde{P}$.